# How to modify the initial conditon inside the function scipy odeint

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

When i try to solve a differential equation, I have found that the initial condition is different from before. The initial condition is : `f(0)=0,f'(a)=0`, unlike the condition `f(0)=0,f'(0)=b`

---

the function odeint parameter
`y0 : array`
Initial condition on y (can be a vector).(cite by scipy.org)

---

How do I modify the initial condition y0?

Comment: When you write `f(0)=0,f'(a)=0`, it looks to me as a [boundary value problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem) and not and [ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation). You can use `odeint` only to solve `ODEs`.

Comment: In fact, i don't know how to deal the problem with different argument in boundary value. I just know how to deal the differential problem with the same argument in boundary value @flebool